# Update nested object in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I looked for two days on the web but I am still blocked to update a child object of a parent object.

My parent:

```
class Pass < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :fields
 attr_accessor :fields_attributes
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :fields, :allow_destroy => true, :update_only => true
```

My child:

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :pass
```

My form view:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :fields do |field|%>
    <div class="control-group">
      <%= field.label :id, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= field.label :value, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
    <%= field.text_field :value, :class => 'text_field' %>
       </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

I also define permitted parameters thanks to:

```
def pass_params  params.require(:pass).permit(:pass,
                                              :description,
                                              :organization_name,
                                              :logo_upload,
                                              :icon_upload,
                                              :strip_upload,
                                              fields_attributes: [:id,:value])
  #params.require(:pass).permit!

 end
```

I have no problem to create a pass with 5 fields in my passes_controller

```
def new
 @pass = Pass.new
 5.times {@pass.fields.build}
 #@fields = @pass.fields
 end
```

My problem happens is that child fields of my pass are not updated after an edit of the pass. I always get initial values (at the creation of the pass) of fields.

I tried to update using different ways without success

```
  if @pass.update_attributes(pass_params)
  if @pass.update_attributes[params[:pass][:fields_attributes]]
  if @pass.update_attributes(params[:fields_attributes])
```

When I update my pass, the pass_params looks like this:

```
 {"description"=>"Test22gg", "organization_name"=>"Toto", "fields_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"30", "value"=>"testf"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"29", "value"=>"test"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"28", "value"=>"test"}, "3"=>{"id"=>"27", "value"=>"test"}, "4"=>{"id"=>"26", "value"=>"test"}}}
```

I don't see which requirement or thing I forget to update these fields!

Comment: Why do you have `attr_accessor :fields_attributes` defined in `Pass`?

Comment: Because I have seen some tutorials that say to put this line in order to get it work.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works without the attr_accessor.

Comment: Have a read on difference between `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`, I think your confusion is the two terms.

Comment: Do you know if the last_update attribute of the pass will be updated if I only change child element of the pass?